# How to allow aliases in a typescript/node server?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have aliases in my client app, and I 'm trying to do the same on the backend with typescript. I wrote:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "mails/*": ["src/mails/*"],
      "models/*": ["src/models/*"],
      "routers/*": ["src/routers/*"],
      "routes/*": ["src/routes/*"],
      "utils/*": ["src/utils/*"]
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }
}
```

But then when importing a file such as: `import authRouter from "routers/auth"` , Typescript claims that:

> Cannot find module 'routers/auth' or its corresponding type declarations.

How to allow aliases path in a node/express server?